# how to debug properly in php

Tags: php, debugging, echo

I have some 2000 lines of code in php... some place i have some echo here and there to know that this or that is done properly... but i what more tracing and echo on each and every task done... i what echo in function enter and before function return... but all these echo polluate the code and the screen, and it's a nigtmare to remove or comment it out when ready for production...

the question, how to say, echo this and that, but when i say debug off, stop echo..how do you that in your code... what i tought was

```
global $debug_echo;
$debug_echo = true;

if ($debug_echo) {echo "function xyz - start";}
if ($debug_echo) {echo "function xyz - end";}
...
...
```

so with this, i can turn debug everywhere with one change... does it make sense ?

Comment: I'm currently using http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ for my IDE with http://xdebug.org/ for debugging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a core file, such as config.php (which is usually included in all sub files in a web app), have something similar to this:

```
$debug = true;

if($debug){ 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);  
}else{ 
    error_reporting(0); 
}
```

then just change true to false to disable debugging.

If you want to dump errors in the middle of scripts, such as MySQL queries, then that's a whole different kettle of fish.

Check out this slideshow: http://www.slideshare.net/asgrim1/errors-exceptions-logging-php-hants-oct-13

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do for debugging, would be to use a constant. So at the top of your file, or wherever you want to declare debug mode on or off you do this

```
define('DEBUG', true);
```

Then to check you just want to do

```
if(DEBUG === true) { echo 'something here'; }
```

You only have to declare the constant once, and then it's available throughout the entire scope of the code, providing it's declared somewhere.

Comment: a define var act as global ?

Comment: It's not a variable it's a constant, which will be used as a global and cannot be redefined. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do:

```
function is_dev() {
  return isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] AND $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] === 'DEV')
}
```

..In your apache virtual host configuration / .htaccess

```
SetEnv APP_ENV DEV
```

If you are using a framework or creating your SQL queries dynamically, you can output them if `is_dev()` returns true.

```
if(is_dev()) {
  echo $sql;
}
```